# Align div to bottom of the page in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to use methods from stack questions, but nothing works for me, despite project is very simple.

```
<div class="fluid-container">
    <div id="app-row" class="row">
        <div id="app" class="col-xs-5">
            <div class="top-navbar">
            Top
            </div>
            <div class="bottom-navbar">
            Bottom
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="map-container" class="col-xs-7">
            <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

style.css

```
.fluid-container {
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}

.row {
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
}

html, body, .fluid-container, #app-row, #map-container {
    height: 100%
}

#app-row {
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}

#map-container {
    margin: 0 0 0 0 !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
}

#map {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

What I want to achieve:

Bottom is bottom of the page and Top is on the top of the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using navbar-fixed-bottom:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
    <div class="container">
         My footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is want I wanted, but the problem is that this footer is on the whole page, I want only on the column (notice col-xs-5)

Comment: As as alternative you could try using class="affix" on the div you want to remain fixed.

Comment: I think it's not working, could you paste working example?

Comment: You could try this in your css: .bottom-navbar {position:absolute;
 bottom:0;}

Answer (score 2):

Just use `position:fixed`on both div.

[Here a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3au2rxu/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using bootstrap 4 flexbox.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between">
   <div></div>
   <div>bottom content</div>
</div>
```